# Power Query: M code for column comparison

Tags: powerquery

Is there a way to use Power Query editor to compare two columns of data for similarities?

See sample file below - I need to compare two address columns and return whether they 'exact match', 'partial match', 'no match'. The left three columns are provided to me, I need the logic (M code) to perform (insert) the column titled 'Type of Match' in snippet below.

Any ideas? I am currently using =Text.Contains ([Addr1], [Office Address 1]) which results in a TRUE/FALSE column, however, this logic won't return the exact logic required (see: Brookhouser Rd and Brookhouse Rd)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmiQE.png)

Comment: You're looking for [fuzzy matching](https://support.microsoft.com/office/create-a-fuzzy-match-power-query-ffdd5082-c0c8-4c8e-a794-bd3962b90649). There's also [`Table.AddFuzzyClusterColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/table-addfuzzyclustercolumn) for more control.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I don't think either of those solutions will work in this instance. The first one has to do with merging tables or queries based on Fuzzy matching. And I'm not finding that Fuzzy clustering has the capability to 'compare' two columns of data (all the articles I found show clustering around one column of data outputed to a second.

Comment: You can simply merge the query onto itself -- add a row number, then join based on both the row number (which will always succeed) and fuzzily join `Addr1` onto `Office Address 1` (which either succeeds, in which case the match is either exact if the columns are the same, and partial if not, or fails, in which case there's no match). For fuzzy clustering, add the clustering first on both columns, then compare the new columns.